# Creating Turtle objects in a class with python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create turtle objects with a class for my project which is a game. Each "Plane" object consists of:

```
plane3 = RawTurtle(screen)
plane3.ht()
plane3.color("red")
plane3.shape("plane.gif")
plane3.penup()
plane3.speed('fastest')
plane3.setposition(-270, 200)
plane3.setheading(360)
```

When putting this into a class and looking at other stack overflows questions to find out what to do, i threw together the following code:

```
    class planes():
    def __init__(self):
        self.RawTurtle = RawTurtle(screen)
        #self.hideturtle()
        self.color = "red"
        self.shape = ("plane.gif")
        #self.penup()
        self.speed = "fastest"
        self.setposition = (-270, 100)
        self.setheading = 360

Plane4 = planes()
```

When the code is run the turtle takes no shape or colour and is just a black triangle even though it causes no errors. However, errors do occur with the `plane.hideturtle` and `plane.penup()` functions which is why they are commented out.

File "C:/Users/marco/Desktop/Trooper shooter/TrooperShooter.py", line 694, in **init**
    self.hideturtle()
AttributeError: 'planes' object has no attribute 'hideturtle'

Planes outside the class work perfectly and all planes are exactly identical. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`hideturtle()` and `penup()` are both methods for the `RawTurtle` class, you haven't defined them for your `planes` class. So instead of this:

```
self.hideturtle()
self.penup()
```

you should have this:

```
self.RawTurtle.hideturtle()
self.RawTurtle.penup()
```

Comment: Thanks alot! When changing this for the shape and colour the turtle changes too.

Comment: However, now i gave a problem using the .xcor() function as apparently the class has no xcor. I added - self.RawTurtle.xcor = (self.RawTurtle.xcor()) in the the class and they still have no attribute 'xcor'

Answer (score 0):

I believe your real problem is that your designed your plane class such that it ***has a*** turtle instead of designing it such that it ***is a*** turtle.

Taking the *has a* approach, every time you want to enable some additional turtle feature on your plane, you have to add a method to pass the call through to the contained turtle.  Taking the *is a* approach, all turtle methods are in play:

```
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, RIGHT

class Plane(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen)

        self.hideturtle()

        self.color('red')
        self.shape('plane.gif')
        # self.speed('fastest')  # commented out while debugging
        self.penup()
        self.setposition(-270, 100)
        self.setheading(0)

        self.showturtle()

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=400)
canvas.pack(side=RIGHT)

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.register_shape('plane.gif')

plane4 = Plane()
plane4.forward(400)

screen.mainloop()
```